# Python - grouping variables containing strings

Tags: python

I have a number of variables that contain strings. What would be a preferred method to group this data?

This variables will be used as arguments in other functions that collect data(CPU/Memory usage, time, speed) when files are transferred. e.g. `collect_file_copy_data("data_size", get_data_size("file_path")`

1 and 2 are the things that first come to my mind.

1.Create a function containing a dictionary with `"string":"string"` format:

```
def get_data(name):
    data = {
        "data_size" : "Size of data",
        "cpu_usage" : "CPU Usage
        ...
        }
    return data[name]
```

2.Create a function containing a dictionary with `"int":"string"` format:

```
def get_data(name_position):
    data = {
        1 : "Size of data",
        2 : "CPU Usage
        ...
        }
    return data[name_position]
```

3. Other better ideas?

Comment: 2 would be better as a list or tuple (depending on whether you change anything in it). You wouldn't need to turn it into a dict.

Comment: But the big thing is it depends on how you want to access it and what you want to do with it.

Comment: I updated the post with more details

Comment: Ok, if the data isn't going to change then either a tuple (where you'd use the index as a number) or as Adam suggested a named tuple if you're wanting to index by name. It really is up to yourself, but named is easier for a human to read.

Comment: Yes, human readable code is a big plus, so I will go with [Adam Scott](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7850705/adam-scott) 's suggestion with [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple). Thanks [Keef Baker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3296885/keef-baker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of using [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) ?

Comment: I did not know about this data type. It is the right choice for what I need, especially that it's more human readable. Thanks [Adam Scott](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7850705/adam-scott)